# 2 separate sets of network notifications appearing

Tags: gnome, networkmanager, cinnamon

Is there a way to find the source application of a GNOME desktop notification? I am getting 2 sets of notifications during any sort of network connection/disconnection event. They are different than the normal NetworkManager notifications. This is on Debian 10. I believe I was playing around with `wicd` when this started, and persisted even after removal of `wicd`.

I have already disabled notifications for network manager, and these separate notifications keep coming.

For example, the notification would say

```
 Now connected to 802-11-wireless "wifi_network"
```

Comment: Do you still see the `wicd`icon-tray on your desktop gui ?

Answer (score 1):

It's most probably `wicd` or "family" ... but you wrote that you got rid of `wicd`... so the question is: what did you do to install, and then to remove `wicd`?  If installed from a package with `apt` or `apt-get`, the following, along with a restart should be enough.

```
$ sudo apt remove wicd wicd-gtk --autoremove   # won't work if you installed from source
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get purge wicd wicd-gtk --autoremove
```

If you run `systemd` stop and disable the `wicd` service with:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop wicd.service
$ sudo systemctl disable wicd.service
```

On Debian platforms with Gnome, the daemon may come (or not) with a separate notification module (like [this](https://github.com/GNOME/notification-daemon) or a packaged version of it, for example) to enable visual notifications about network status. If so you'd need to disable and purge that as well.

Comment: I did still have `wicd-gtk` and `wicd-daemon` still installed, but these were not the root of the problem. After attempting this to no avail, and removing `~/.config/autostart/wicd-gtk.desktop` , I ran `ps aux` to look for anything. I guessed and killed `nm-tray`, this stopped it. After removing the package for `nm-tray`, the issue was resolved. Turns out the `NetworkManager` package handles the tray and icons by itself, and for some reason I had installed nm-tray.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `nm-tray` was installed along with `NetworkManager`. After removing residual `wicd` files from the system with the issue still persisting, I checked the output of `ps aux` for clues. After taking a wild guess and killing `nm-tray`, the issue was resolved. Removing the package for `nm-tray` resolved the issue. Apparently the `NetworkManager` package handles notifications and tray icons itself, and `nm-tray` was launching an entirely separate set of notifications.